# Why is my dependency property on a custom UserControl not recognized?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a `UserControl` called `BranchFilter`, with the following property:

```
private int? _branchId;
public int? LocalBranchId
{
    get { return _branchId; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _branchId, value);
        OnBranchChanged();
    }
}
```

In the same control, I register a dependency property so that I can bind the branch id to a viewmodel:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BranchIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LocalBranchId), typeof(int?), typeof(BranchFilter), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

And when I try and access this property, without even binding it, in a view, like so:

```
<controls:BranchFilter Grid.Row="0" BranchId="0">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="BranchChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadItems}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</controls:BranchFilter>
```

I get the compile errors:

> The member "BranchId" is not recognized or is not accessible.
>
> The property 'BranchId' was not found in type 'BranchFilter'.
>
> The property 'BranchId' does not exist in XML namespace
> 'clr-namespace:ApptBook.Client.Modules.Common.Controls'

I have followed every example, but they're all the same, for adding the dependency property, but everything I have tried has failed. What could be wrong with something so simple?

Comment: I guess it should be LocalBranchIdProperty

Comment: Use `propdp` code-snippet to generate dependency property *properly*.

Comment: @Sinatr I don't have the snippet.

Comment: @ProfK, I am sure you have. Type `propdp` and hit `Tab` key twice.

Comment: Note that a correct dependency property declaration requires a CLR property wrapper that calls `GetValue` and `SetValue` in its get and set accessors. You can not declare a dependency property that wraps a CLR property. See [Custom Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you not be accessing it using `LocalBranchId` instead of `BranchId`?

```
<controls:BranchFilter Grid.Row="0" LocalBranchId="0">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="BranchChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadItems}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</controls:BranchFilter>
```

I would also rename the `DependencyProperty` from `BranchIdProperty` to `LocalBranchIdProperty`.

Comment: Ah, yes. I misunderstood the dependency property registration to create a wrapper around the POCO property, but it actually registers the POCO property as a dependency property, so I should still access the POCO one, and it will have the behaviour of a dependency property.

Answer (score 1):

You should correctly declare `LocalBranchId` as a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LocalBranchIdProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(LocalBranchId), typeof(int?), typeof(BranchFilter));

public int? LocalBranchId
{
    get { return (int?)GetValue(LocalBranchIdProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LocalBranchIdProperty, value); }
}
```

---

If you need to get notified when the property value changes, you can register a
PropertyChangedCallback by PropertyMetadata:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LocalBranchIdProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(LocalBranchId), typeof(int?), typeof(BranchFilter),
        new PropertyMetadata(LocalBranchIdPropertyChanged));

public int? LocalBranchId
{
    get { return (int?)GetValue(LocalBranchIdProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LocalBranchIdProperty, value); }
}

private static void LocalBranchIdPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (BranchFilter)obj;
    var id = (int?)e.NewValue;
    ...
}
```